# Setting a static route to a LAN destination in Archer D7 router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing

I own an Archer D7 modem. I have recently switched from DSL to FTTH, so my ISP provided me with their own ONT (Huawei HG8245Q) with phone, Ethernet and Wifi ports (like if Wifi was a "port" ever). I have a Raspberry Pi that works as VPN gateway to a remote site.

With old setup, D7 (which I bought because of this) had static route to Raspberry, and forwarded the rest to the DSL port. The fiber modem allows me to disable DHCP if I like, [but doesn't allow me to modify routing tables](http://setuprouter.com/router/huawei/hg8245/general-40849-large.htm): the linked article is for a modem without final Q.

Currently I succeeded in disabling ONT DHCP, put D7 in same LAN as every device and enabled DHCP on it. However I had to tell D7 to use ONT as default gateway. Internet works. While the D7 has the routing information, no client will ever go to it to address the remote VLAN (I'd have to tell my phone a routing table).

I thought I could input a static route "0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0" into the D7 through the ONT LAN address and keep remote VLAN via Raspberry LAN address, but D7 refuses 0.0.0.0 to override the default route.+

[This article](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/716990/Tp-Link-Archer-D7.html?page=84) shows that with D7 you can configure a static default gateway, but my control panel doesn't look that. The default gateway can **only** be a WAN interface in my case

I **know** I can use LAN1 port as WAN port and put D7 behind ONT, so that I have two levels of NAT. That is the answer if I don't find another way.

But I wanted to ask: how do I specify a static route on a D7 router to a device on my LAN? It will be **very** useful to divert guest network traffic via Raspberry Tor :-)

Comment: I understand that sometimes I overcomplicate the whole my life, but I just like to do complicated stuff

Comment: Static routes need not be default routes. Changing the default route from the WAN connection will disable your Internet access. You must apply a static route to a router (layer-3) interface, not an interface that is part of a switch (layer-2) in the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, just add specific routes for your VLANs. You probably still want the ONT to be used as a gateway for the public Internet – so there are just three 'private' ranges to cover.

```
NETWORK         NETMASK
10.0.0.0/8      255.0.0.0
172.16.0.0/12   255.240.0.0
192.168.0.0/16  255.255.0.0
```

---

But let's say you *really* want to override the default gateway for every single thing.

The most specific route will be used, so a common trick is to divide the internet into two routes: `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1`. While somewhat ugly, this will always take priority over the "default" `0.0.0.0/0` route.

```
NETWORK         NETMASK
0.0.0.0/1       128.0.0.0
128.0.0.0/1     128.0.0.0
```

If tnat's not accepted by your router, start at 1.0.0.0 instead (luckily `0.0.0.0/8` doesn't actually contain valid IP addresses so it can be omitted) – these will cover the whole lot:

```
NETWORK         NETMASK
1.0.0.0/8       255.0.0.0
2.0.0.0/7       254.0.0.0
4.0.0.0/6       252.0.0.0
8.0.0.0/5       248.0.0.0
16.0.0.0/4      240.0.0.0
32.0.0.0/3      224.0.0.0
64.0.0.0/2      192.0.0.0
128.0.0.0/1     128.0.0.0
```

If that's still not accepted by your router, spam it with /8 routes which cover everything from `1.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`:

```
NETWORK         NETMASK
1.0.0.0/8       255.0.0.0
2.0.0.0/8       255.0.0.0
3.0.0.0/8       255.0.0.0
[...]
221.0.0.0/8     255.0.0.0
222.0.0.0/8     255.0.0.0
223.0.0.0/8     255.0.0.0
```

(Skip 127, that's loopback. You can stop before 224, that's where the multicast range starts.)

And if *that* doesn't work, then I'm sorry to inform you but your router is garbage.

Comment: The router is clever, won't accept 0.0.0.0 :-)

Comment: Then it should accept `1.0.0.0`. See updated post.